# How to Update a item array using typicode/lowdb file database?

Tags: javascript, json, database, express

Hi i'm testing a express app using a typicode/lowdb json file as database but i can't get update function to work.
Here is some code example:

The typicode/lowdb db.json

```
{
      "posts": [
        {
          "name": "first post",
          "desc": "first desc",
          "slug": "first-post",
          "id": "uuid.v4()"
        },
       {
          "name": "second post",
          "desc": "second desc",
          "slug": "second-post",
          "id": "uuid.v4()"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Create/update/delete.js

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var low = require('lowdb');
var storage = require('lowdb/file-async');
var db = low('./database/db.json',{ storage: storage });

var add = function (item) {
var id = uuid.v4();
item.id = id;
db('posts').push(item);  
};

var getById = function (id) {
return db('posts').find({ id: id});
};

var update = function (item,id) {
item.id = id;
 db('posts').chain().find({ id: id}).assign(item).value();
//nothing happens the db.json file is not updated

//using console log i get this from update:
             {
              "name": "first post edited",
              "desc": "first desc edited",
              "slug": "first-post-edited",
              "id": "undifined"
            }
console.log(db('posts').chain().find({ id: id}).assign(item).value());

};
```

example of handle-the-update.js

```
 exports.update = router.post('/update',function (req, res) {

 db.update({name:req.body.name,desc:req.body.desc,slug:slug,id:req.params.id});
res.redirect('/post');
});
```

create delete and get the post by-id functions work's fine the only problem is the update.
Any idea why this happens? I tested **.filter()** , **.where()** but nothing works the db.json file don't update

Answer (score 2):

have today the same problem. Not sure if the lowDB Readme on GitHub changed since your question, but now it work like described.

Here an example of your code:

```js
var low = require('lowdb');
var fileAsync = require('lowdb/file-async');
var db = low('./database/db.json',{ storage: fileAsync });
var postStore = db.get('posts');

postStore.find({ id: "uuid.v4()" })
   .assign({name: "new name"})
   .value();
```

This should work. Have tested is today.

It update both of your example records, cause they have same id.

Answer (score 2):

According to lowdb guide you have to call write() method.
So replace your string:

```
db('posts').chain().find({ id: id}).assign(item).value();
```

To:

```
db('posts').chain().find({ id: id}).assign(item).write();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var low = require('lowdb');
const db = low('db-posts.json')

db.defaults({ posts: [], user: {} })
  .value()

db.get('posts')
  .push({ id: 1, title: 'lowdb is awesome'})
  .value()

db.set('user.name', 'typicode')
  .value()
```